# Does this RegExp string need some escaping?

Tags: javascript, regex

I was trying to use a RegExp so that I could insert a string variable at some later point. But even this first attempt without said variable won't work. What is missing?

There's a nice jsbin linked that shows the behavior.

```
const DOCS = [
    "My Report – March 2019.pdf",
    "My Report – May 2019.pdf",
    "My Diary - April-May 2019.pdf",
    "My Diary - February-March 2019.pdf"
]

const title_month_year = new RegExp("(.*) - (January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December) (19|20\d{2})")


DOCS.forEach(
    mag = mag.replace(/–/g, "-");
//  if (title_month_year.test(mag)) {   <--- does not match
    if (/(.*) - (January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December) (19|20\d{2})/.test(mag)) {
        console.log('we have a match');   
    }
```

https://jsbin.com/lomolew/edit?js,console

Comment: You are using a different kind of hypen `–` vs `-`

Comment: Good catch @Thefourthbird - mdash vs ndash

Comment: OK, guess I deserve the -1 for not including more code in the pasted text, but the m-dash fix was present in the jsbin, and the code there still doesn't match.

Comment: Not my downvote, but the reason you get only 2 matches is that the third and the fourth string contains 2 months with an hyphen in between `April-May` and that is not matched by the pattern.

Comment: Yes, I only want to match 2 of the 4 at this stage. FIguring out this RegExp will help match the double-month strings (later) much easier.

Comment: But what is the exacty question right now?

Comment: I was getting zero matches because the \d was not escaped. Got my answer - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to escape the \d{2}

it should be \\d{2} inside of a RegExp string.

Answer (score 1):

```
const DOCS = [
    "My Report – March 2019.pdf",
    "My Report – May 2019.pdf",
    "My Diary - April-May 2019.pdf",
    "My Diary - February-March 2019.pdf"
]

const months = {
    "January": "01",
    "Jan": "01",
    "February": "02",
    "Feb": "02",
    "March": "03",
    "Mar": "03",
    "April": "04",
    "Apr": "04",
    "May": "05",
    "June": "06",
    "Jun": "06",
    "July": "07",
    "Jul": "07",
    "August": "08",
    "Aug": "08",
    "September": "09",
    "Sep": "09",
    "October": "10",
    "Oct": "10",
    "November": "11",
    "Nov": "11",
    "December": "12",
    "Dec": "12"
}


let docsCopy = DOCS.map(m => {
    var mReplace = m.replace(/^(.+)(?:\s[-–]\s)+(.+)\s(\d+)(.+)/, (match, p1, p2, p3, p4) => {

        var p2C = p2.split('-').map(item=>{
            return months[item]
        }).join('-')
        console.log(p2C)
        return p1 + ' ' + p3 + '-' + p2C + p4

    })

    return mReplace



});

console.log(docsCopy)
```

Comment: Thanks - saw a regex trick or two I can use! The actual script needs to take care of maybe 5-6 date formats, so I'm forced to use simpler regex to handle each format on a one-by-one basis.

Comment: If not fixed format (1-2 months connection),you can only capture the string, Open your mind

Answer (score 0):

As the fourth bird already pointed out you're using a different type of hypen.
What you could do is to adjust your regex to include either both type of hypens:
`const title_month_year = new RegExp("(.*) (-|–) (January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December) (19|20\d{2})")`

Please note that with solution your grouping values will be off by one after the first entry (so instead of 3 elements you now have 4, the first being whatever is in front of the hypen, the second being the hypen type, the third one being the month and the fourth one being the year.

Or to just look for a character instead of a hypen:
`const title_month_year = new RegExp("(.*) . (January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December) (19|20\d{2})")`